# Facebook Meta tags parsing

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, facebook-opengraph

If I add a link from my website to facebook, it acts as if it doesn't have the open graph meta tags and just shows the link. I do have meta tags on that page.

In fact, after I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and enter the link there it shows that the scraping is done fine.

Then, if I post the link again, the link displays correctly.

Why does this happen? I can think of one alternative - facebook has some workers who scrape the links posted, if its the first time that link was encountered. Once scraped, all other posts with same links will displayed the scraped data. The debug scraper has priority to input the data instead of the workers.

Is this the case?